# How to restrict some url in chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, manifest

I want to restrict some urls in a chrome packaged app, but when I try to use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener in background.js in order to detect the call, I get error upon installing the app, 'webRequest' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app."
My manifest is as below

```
...
"manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js", "js/chromeUtility.js","js/customchromeserver/wsc-chrome.js"],
      "persistent": false
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://www.xyz.com/*",  // want to block this url
    "identity",
    "storage",
    "webview",
    ...
```

How do I restrict a url in my chrome app , any suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could finaly do it since the url I want to block is loaded via webview, therefore I have checked it by using webview event listener for new window something like - webview.addEventListener('newwindow'), )